# Why doesn't this TSQL LIKE statement always find commas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I expect this to join when ApptIdList is '12345' and not join when ApptIDList is '12345,67890'

```
SELECT *
FROM WAITINGROOM a
LEFT JOIN APPOINTMENTS b on b.ApptId = (CASE WHEN (a.ApptIdList LIKE '%,%') THEN -1 ELSE CONVERT(INT, a.ApptIdList) END)
```

The column WAITINGROOM.ApptIdList is a comma-delimited string list that matches the int key APPOINTMENTS.ApptId

(Yes, I'm aware that this is a bad way to design a database. It's not my database, and I can't change it.)

This seems to work on my copy of the database, but on some user's databases it throws errors like

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '236656,236655' to
>   data type int

That looks to me like on some machines '236656,236655' LIKE '%,%' is false, which is very surprising to me, and I have not found a way to reproduce that behaviour on my machine. Is that even possible? Or is something even stranger going on here?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. The users have various versions, all 2008 R2 or above.

Comment: Perhaps they are not using `case` for the `join` condition.  The logic should be safe with `case`.

Comment: To clarify: my code is using case, running on the user's databases, and it is not as safe as I expected it to be.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query that's actually executing? If the query is formed programmatically the actual query may not be the query that you are expecting to execute.

Comment: The query isn't formed programmatically. The real query is longer, but the join is the same as what I posted above. There are no CONVERTs or CASTs in the rest of the query, there are no comma delimited lists in other columns, and there are no other references to the comma delimited list in the query.

Comment: Unfortunately, there do seem to be instances, especially on earlier versions of SQL Server, where `WHEN` expressions in a `CASE` will be evaluated even though an earlier `WHEN` condition should render that evaluation unnecessary. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945) on the DBA Stack Exchange site for examples. Given this, I suspect that Gordon's answer, reformulating the query to avoid the dependence on `CASE` short-circuiting, is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I would convert the suspect string into `varbinary` and examined the actual letter codes. As it appears, there are many different possible commas - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma - and you are checking for only one of them.

Comment: Alright Joe Farrel, if you post an answer below saying that CASE doesn't always short-circuit, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, Erland Sommarskog raised [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) back in 2010. (All the formatting/authorship got stripped when this got migrated from Connect). No sign MS are ever going to *fix* this kind of thing.

Comment: @JoeFarrell . . . The situations that I'm familiar with either involve aggregation or constructs outside a single `select` query.  This use of the `case` expression is pretty basic and should follow the defined semantics.  I'm surprised that this would change between versions . . . but perhaps some optimization in a later version happens to require evaluating all `then`/`else` expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Do the conversion in the other direction:

```
SELECT *
FROM WAITINGROOM wr LEFT JOIN
     APPOINTMENTS a
     ON wr.ApptIdList + ',' LIKE CAST(a.ApptId as VARCHAR(255)) + ',%';
```

With the conversion in this direction, there is no danger of a conversion going amiss.

Comment: That was my first thought too, although the appointments table can get real big, so I would prefer a query that doesn't have to scan the whole thing.

But most of all I would like to know how the error was even possible in the first place.